Android Splash screen doesn't show on the screen
MainActivity2.kt
package com.example.screen

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.screen.ui.theme.ScreenTheme


class MainActivity2 : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2) // Set the content view to activity_main2.xml

        setContent {
            ScreenTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    ScreenTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}

activity_main2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_screen">


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

I'm a totally beginner in android studio.
Now, I am trying to make a splash screen.
First, I import a svg file(splash screen) using vector asset into drawable. The name of the file is splash_screen.xml.
Next, I include the file in the activity_main2.xml.
I also set content view for activity_main2
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2) 

However, when i run the app, the screen just shows one line of text (Hello, Android).
Can i know how can i connect the splash screen to the mainactivity2.kt.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

You're using both Compose and XML in the same activity. Remove the code below setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)  in the onCreate method.
